# How can I take an exsiting flat 2d SVG path, and extrude it into a bar shape?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, geojson

Lets say I have a square drawn with a path. What I want to be able to do is take that bar and based on data, extrude it up, into a pseudo 3d bar shape.

I want to do that, but with any polygonal path. So I could have a pseudo 3d triangle bar or octagonal bar etc.

The idea is to do this with geojson data, but I haven't found any resources that will allow me to do this.

Any ideas?

Here's a jsfiddle with an example shape.

```
<div>
 <svg height="210" width="400">
   <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
 </svg> 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kwdy3x6c/

Comment: Try with drop shadows. Just remove all the blur so it will be a solid shape.

Comment: Or instead of drop shadows, clone, like so. http://jsbin.com/lecoyo/4/edit

Comment: @GaryHayes Thanks! I used this technique to get the effect I needed!